# Using Form states in Panel Styles: How to overcome 'outdated' error message

Tags: theming, forms, panels

Drupal's FORM API lets you specify [Form States](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7). These have a handy visibility state are that let you show/hide parts of a form depending on which fields have been filled in. It's a good way of reducing clutter on a form.

I am building my own custom Panel Style. The style settings has a lot of options, so I want to use the Form Visibility State to hide them.

I have added the code following the tutorials [here](http://www.deckfifty.com/blog/2012-11/drupal-form-api-conditional-fields) and [here](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-build-beautiful-forms-drupal-7-video-presentation). However, when I select an option on the form, I get this error message:

> The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below
>   and then reload this page.

How can I fix this?

This [Dr Drupal tutorial](http://drupaldr.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/form-has-become-outdated-copy-any.html) suggests I need to use $form['form_build_id'], $form['form_id'], $form['form_token']. However, the tutorial is quite terse, so I'm not sure how to add them to my code.

The code for my panel style is here:

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * Returns form render array.
 */
function coloroptions($form, $form_state)
{
    $form['color_default'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select a Colour'),
        '#options' => array(
            '000000' => t('Black'),
            'ffffff' => t('White'),
            'custom' => t('Custom')
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_default'])) ? $form['color_default'] : '000000',
        '#description' => t('The Colour you want to use')
    );


    $form['color_custom'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('background color for pane'),
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="color_default"]' => array(
                    'value' => 'custom'
                )
            )
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_custom'])) ? $form['color_custom'] : '',
        '#description' => t('The Colour you want to use')
    );

    $form['color_location'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Box around'),
        '#options' => array(
            'pane' => t('Each pane'),
            'region' => t('Each region')
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_location'])) ? $form['color_location'] : 'pane',
        '#description' => t('Choose whether to include the box around each pane (piece of content) or region (each column or region)')
    );



    return $form;


}




/**
 * @file
 *   Definition of the 'color' panel style.
 */

/* Place this file in themename/plugins/styles/STYLENAME/
/* In theme.INFO add the following:
/* ;----------// Plugin Panels
plugins[panels][layouts] = plugins/layouts
plugins[panels][styles] = plugins/styles
/* Reset your cahce afterwards.  */


$plugin = array(
    'title' => t('Example: Color text style'),
    'description' => t('Simply changes the text color of a pane, as an example.'),

    // Names the function to render a pane. Only required for pane styles.
    'render pane' => 'panels_colors_style_pane',

    // Names the function to render a region. Only required for pane styles.
    'render region' => 'panels_colors_style_region',

    // Names the function providing settings form for the pane. (optional)
    'pane settings form' => 'panels_colors_style_pane_settings',

    // Names the function providing settings form for the region. (optional)
    'settings form' => 'panels_colors_style_region_settings',

    // Provide a template to be used by Pane and/or Region. (optional)    
    'hook theme' => array(
        'panels_colors_box' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'content' => NULL
            ),
            'path' => path_to_theme('plugins/styles/colors'),
            'template' => 'panels-colors-box'
        )
    )

);



/**
 * Settings form for the pane.
 *
 * Any form will do here. The settings will come through to the theme
 * function in $pane->style['settings'].
 * Use form API to construct the form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7
 *
 * @param $style_settings
 *   The $style_settings if they've already been set.
 * @return
 *   The form.
 */


function panels_colors_style_pane_settings($style_settings)
{
    return drupal_get_form('coloroptions');

    return $form;
}



/**
 * Settings form for the region.
 *
 * Any form will do here. The settings will come through to the theme
 * function in $pane->style['settings'].
 * Use form API to construct the form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7
 *
 * @param $style_settings
 *   The $style_settings if they've already been set.
 * @return
 *   The form.
 */


function panels_colors_style_region_settings($style_settings)
{
    /*    $form['color'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('background color for pane'),
    '#default_value' => (isset($style_settings['color'])) ? $style_settings['color'] : '#000000',
    '#description' => t('Select the background color for the region.')
    );

    $form['color_location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Box around'),
    '#options' => array(
    'pane' => t('Each pane'),
    'region' => t('Each region')
    ),
    '#default_value' => (isset($style_settings['color_location'])) ? $style_settings['color_location'] : 'pane',
    '#description' => t('Choose whether to include the box around each pane (piece of content) or region (each column or region)')
    );*/


    return drupal_get_form('coloroptions');


    return $form;

    dpm($form);

}



/**
 * Render the pane content.
 *
 * The name of this function is referenced in hook_default_panels_styles(), and
 * it's free-form, but of course be careful to namespace it.
 * But the name is just theme_<render pane> where "<render pane>" is what you
 * put into the array above.
 *
 * This is optional, but shows how a plugin can render a pane.
 *
 * Please remember that you have to rebuild the theme registry after
 * introducing this function or changing its name.
 *
 * @param $content
 *   The content of the block to be rendered. It has a title and a content.
 * @param $pane
 * @param $display
 * @return
 *   rendered content
 */
function theme_panels_colors_style_pane($vars)
{
    kpr($vars);
    $display        = $vars['display'];
    $content        = $vars['content'];
    $pane           = $vars['pane'];
    $style_settings = $pane->style['settings'];
    $color          = $style_settings['color'];
    $output         = "";
    if (!empty($content->title)) {
        $output .= "<h3>$content->title</h3>";
    }

    // For this simple example, wrap the content in a div with style.
    // We could have loaded extra css, etc.
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'legendary') . '/plugins/styles/colors/yellow.css', 'theme');
    $output .= "<div style='background-color:";
    $output .= $color;
    $output .= ";'>";

    $output .= theme('panels_pane', array(
        'content' => $content,
        'pane' => $pane,
        'display' => $display
    ));
    //   $output = theme('panels_colors_box', array('content' => $output));
    $output .= "</div>";
    return $output;
}





/**
 * The function which will render the panel or region with this style.
 *
 * This is optional, but shows how the plugin can be used to change the
 * rendering of a panel or region.
 *
 * @param $display
 * @param $panel_id
 * @param $panes
 * @param $settings
 * @return
 *   Rendered output for the panel.
 */
function theme_panels_colors_style_region($vars)
{
    $display   = $vars['display'];
    $region_id = $vars['region_id'];
    $panes     = $vars['panes'];
    $settings  = $vars['settings'];
    $output    = '';

    $color_default = $settings['color_default'];
    $color_custom  = $settings['color_custom'];

    if ($color_default != 'custom') {
        $color = $color_default;
    } else {
        $color = $color_custom;
    }

    $output = "<div style='text-decoration: underline; background-color: #$color;'>";

    $where = empty($settings['color_location']) ? 'pane' : $settings['color_location'];

    foreach ($panes as $pane_id => $pane) {
        if ($where == 'pane') {
            // If you are NOT using a tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:
            //    $output .= $pane;

            //If you ARE using a Tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:        
            $output .= theme('panels_colors_box', array(
                'content' => $pane
            ));

        }

        else {
            //Loop throught to gather each pane and put them into $allpanes          
            $allpanes .= $pane;
            $print_separator = TRUE;
        }


    }

    if ($where == 'region') {
        // If you are NOT using a tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:
        //$output .= $allpanes;

        // If you are using a tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:
        $output .= theme('panels_colors_box', array(
            'content' => $allpanes
        ));
    }

    $output .= "</div>";
    return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out!

The form part has to be moved to where `return drupal_get_form('coloroptions');` is.

Then, the visibility options for the Form state have to be updated, so they match the Panel Style form options correctly.

I have posted the code below, as it will make more sense to someone having the same problem:

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * @file
 *   Definition of the 'color' panel style.
 */

/* Place this file in themename/plugins/styles/STYLENAME/
/* In theme.INFO add the following:
/* ;----------// Plugin Panels
plugins[panels][layouts] = plugins/layouts
plugins[panels][styles] = plugins/styles
/* Reset your cahce afterwards.  */


$plugin = array(
    'title' => t('Example: Color text style'),
    'description' => t('Simply changes the text color of a pane, as an example.'),

    // Names the function to render a pane. Only required for pane styles.
    'render pane' => 'panels_colors_style_pane',

    // Names the function to render a region. Only required for pane styles.
    'render region' => 'panels_colors_style_region',

    // Names the function providing settings form for the pane. (optional)
    'pane settings form' => 'panels_colors_style_pane_settings',

    // Names the function providing settings form for the region. (optional)
    'settings form' => 'panels_colors_style_region_settings',

    // Provide a template to be used by Pane and/or Region. (optional)    
    'hook theme' => array(
        'panels_colors_box' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'content' => NULL
            ),
            'path' => path_to_theme('plugins/styles/colors'),
            'template' => 'panels-colors-box'
        )
    )

);


/**
 * Settings form for the pane.
 *
 * Any form will do here. The settings will come through to the theme
 * function in $pane->style['settings'].
 * Use form API to construct the form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7
 *
 * @param $style_settings
 *   The $style_settings if they've already been set.
 * @return
 *   The form.
 */


function panels_colors_style_pane_settings($style_settings) {
    $form['color_default'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select a Colour'),
        '#options' => array(
            '000000' => t('Black'),
            'ffffff' => t('White'),
            'custom' => t('custom')
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_default'])) ? $form['color_default'] : '000000',
        '#description' => t('The Colour you want to use')
    );




    $form['color_custom'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('background color for pane'),
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="settings[color_default]"]' => array(
                    'value' => t('custom')
                )

            )
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_custom'])) ? $form['color_custom'] : '',
        '#description' => t('The Colour you want to use')
    );

    $form['color_location'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Box around'),
        '#options' => array(
            'pane' => t('Each pane'),
            'region' => t('Each region')
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_location'])) ? $form['color_location'] : 'pane',
        '#description' => t('Choose whether to include the box around each pane (piece of content) or region (each column or region)')
    );



    return $form;
}


/**
 * Settings form for the region.
 *
 * Any form will do here. The settings will come through to the theme
 * function in $pane->style['settings'].
 * Use form API to construct the form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7
 *
 * @param $style_settings
 *   The $style_settings if they've already been set.
 * @return
 *   The form.
 */

function panels_colors_style_region_settings($style_settings) {
    $form['color_default'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select a Colour'),
        '#options' => array(
            '000000' => t('Black'),
            'ffffff' => t('White'),
            'custom' => t('custom')
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_default'])) ? $form['color_default'] : '000000',
        '#description' => t('The Colour you want to use')
    );




    $form['color_custom'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('background color for pane'),
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="settings[color_default]"]' => array(
                    'value' => t('custom')
                )

            )
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_custom'])) ? $form['color_custom'] : '',
        '#description' => t('The Colour you want to use')
    );

    $form['color_location'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Box around'),
        '#options' => array(
            'pane' => t('Each pane'),
            'region' => t('Each region')
        ),
        '#default_value' => (isset($form['color_location'])) ? $form['color_location'] : 'pane',
        '#description' => t('Choose whether to include the box around each pane (piece of content) or region (each column or region)')
    );

    return $form;

}

/**
 * Render the pane content.
 *
 * The name of this function is referenced in hook_default_panels_styles(), and
 * it's free-form, but of course be careful to namespace it.
 * But the name is just theme_<render pane> where "<render pane>" is what you
 * put into the array above.
 *
 * This is optional, but shows how a plugin can render a pane.
 *
 * Please remember that you have to rebuild the theme registry after
 * introducing this function or changing its name.
 *
 * @param $content
 *   The content of the block to be rendered. It has a title and a content.
 * @param $pane
 * @param $display
 * @return
 *   rendered content
 // */
function theme_panels_colors_style_pane($vars) {
    //kpr($vars);
    $display  = $vars['display'];
    $content  = $vars['content'];
    $pane     = $vars['pane'];
    $settings = $pane->style['settings'];
    $color    = $style_settings['color'];
    $output   = "";
    if (!empty($content->title)) {
        $output .= "<h3>$content->title</h3>";
    }


    $color_default = $settings['color_default'];
    $color_custom  = $settings['color_custom'];

    if ($color_default != 'custom') {
        $color = $color_default;
    } else {
        $color = $color_custom;
    }




    // For this simple example, wrap the content in a div with style.
    // We could have loaded extra css, etc.
    //    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'legendary') . '/plugins/styles/colors/yellow.css', 'theme');
    $output .= "<div style='text-decoration: underline; background-color: #$color; overflow:hidden;'>";

    $output .= theme('panels_pane', array(
        'content' => $content,
        'pane' => $pane,
        'display' => $display
    ));
    //   $output = theme('panels_colors_box', array('content' => $output));

    $output .= $color;

    $output .= "</div>";

    return $output;
}





/**
 * The function which will render the panel or region with this style.
 *
 * This is optional, but shows how the plugin can be used to change the
 * rendering of a panel or region.
 *
 * @param $display
 * @param $panel_id
 * @param $panes
 * @param $settings
 * @return
 *   Rendered output for the panel.
 */
function theme_panels_colors_style_region($vars) {
    $display   = $vars['display'];
    $region_id = $vars['region_id'];
    $panes     = $vars['panes'];
    $settings  = $vars['settings'];
    $output    = '';

    $color_default = $settings['color_default'];
    $color_custom  = $settings['color_custom'];

    if ($color_default != 'custom') {
        $color = $color_default;
    } else {
        $color = $color_custom;
    }

    $output = "<div style='text-decoration: underline; background-color: #$color;'>";

    $where = empty($settings['color_location']) ? 'pane' : $settings['color_location'];

    foreach ($panes as $pane_id => $pane) {
        $display->cssregionstyle[] = $color;
        $settings[]           = $color;
        if ($where == 'pane') {
            // If you are NOT using a tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:
            //    $output .= $pane;

            //If you ARE using a Tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:        
            $output .= theme('panels_colors_box', array(
                'content' => $pane
            ));
        }

        else {
            //Loop throught to gather each pane and put them into $allpanes          
            $allpanes .= $pane;
            $print_separator = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if ($where == 'region') {
        // If you are NOT using a tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:
        $output .= $allpanes;

        // If you are using a tpl.php file (see top of this document), uncomment the following file:
        //  $output .= theme('panels_colors_box', array(
        //    'content' => $allpanes
        // ));

    }

    $output .= "</div>";
    return $output;
}
```